# Careers adverts: location not accurate

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs, advertising, location

On [the Careers front page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), after the **featured jobs** ads, there is a section  **jobs near [your location]**, with a further link to **More [your location] jobs**.

For me, the location it's using is waaaay off by about 100 miles. I suppose this depends on how the location is being looked up, perhaps it's using my ISP's point of presence or something.

Perhaps if it were more accurate the click through rate would be higher?

Comment: Only 100 miles for you? I get them for London, which is 300 miles away.

Comment: Would you really like it if we could accurately pinpoint the location of your house? I know I wouldn't.

Comment: House, no. Town or province, yes.:)

Comment: Are there jobs which are closer to you?

Comment: @ThePower: Aaahhh! Now we know where you live... to within a 600 mile radius, at least :P.

Comment: haha, ok so perhaps an opt in for more accuracy using html5 location api or something similar (I'm guessing the accurate IP to location data is expensive).

Comment: @Matt - ha. Well I'm not in France, so you can take away the south!

Comment: We’ll send the Stack satellites to rescan your area.

Comment: 300 miles away you say? It shows me jobs in Austin, TX while I'm in Dublin, Ireland. Large corporate network, yes. Can we haz an override in the profile please?

Comment: This is a bug I've noticed also and I live in downtown San Francisco (where there are plenty of tech jobs). Careers is offering me "jobs near Aptos" (the location for which I had to look up... it's a tiny town in the Santa Cruz hills between 70 & 100 miles from here).

Comment: I suspected this was a bug, because the ads are for jobs where I used to live. I checked to make sure the location in my profile is up-to-date, and it is. However, it is possible that there are no jobs between  where I live and where I used to live.

Comment: Marking this as status-declined for the same reason as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134567/careers-adverts-on-stack-overflow - just tidying up the bug backlog and there isn't anything specifically, er, buggy here as far as I can tell.

Comment: Cool no worries. Though perhaps an alternative should be used such as a field in the profile page? So maybe 'fixing' IP location should be declined - but an alternative solution would be good.